# Are Future API calls awaited at the end of method execution even if Future.get() is never called?

Tags: java, multithreading, future

So I have a service which tries to make sense out of quite a few different  data sources.

Say i have something like this at the start.

```
Future<ObjectA> objectAFuture = this.objectAClient.getobjectA(Id);
Future<ObjectB> objectBFuture = this.objectBClient.getobjectB(Id);
Future<ObjectC> objectCFuture = this.objectCClient.getobjectC(Id);
Future<ObjectD> objectDFuture = this.objectDClient.getobjectD(Id);
Future<ObjectE> objectEFuture = this.objectEClient.getobjectE(Id);
```

Next I would be calling my own DB, to see which of these I actually do want a result for, and which I already have details around using a local source of data. Instead of waiting for the foreign service to fetch it.

Question : lets say I used.

```
objectAFuture.get();
objectEFuture.get();
```

But for `objectBFuture` , `objectCFuture` , `objectDFuture` , I did not use `.get()`.

Will my function wait for all those to complete when it reaches the end of the function, or will it just send those threads be freed then itself?

Comment: are you asking if `get` is a blocking operation? cause if you do, it is

Comment: if you don't use get, it will not wait for it to complete. Having said that, it will not interrupt the thread also

Answer (score 1):

> ... I did not use `.get()`.

If you don't use `get`, you won't be able to check the result out and process it. But there are no waits until you call `get`.

> Will my function wait for all those to complete when it reaches the end of the function ...

Calling `wait` can block the current thread to complete the computation (if it's necessary - if the result hasn't been assembled yet) and to give you a `Future<T>` instance.

> ... will it just send those threads to be freed then itself?

A thread is free of a process after you get the computed result of this process.

Comment: I think that he ment he didn't use it for objectBFuture, objectCFuture and objectDFuture for which he don't want to get result so he knows he won't be able to check them

Comment: Yes. Basically, I'm firing off these requests at the start. Later on in the services I'm pulling some stuff from DB from which I can figure out whether I really want to call it or not, but that takes quite a bit of parsing, and also using some of those above fired calls. Problem for me being, I want to try and get the final response as early as possible. Most of those calls can take quite some time, I don't really have a problem with making the call. But I'd like to avoid waiting for them, if I don't have to.

Comment: @The0bserver, you came to a particular place where made these calls. There you want to get already computed `Future`s and don't want to wait for `Future`s which aren't done yet,  right?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Yes. The particular place being last line of the service making the Future calls.

Comment: @The0bserver you might set a reasonable time-out for waiting